# problema con los returns de res en un endpoint

Tags: nodejs, express

Buen dia Gente, estoy con un problema al realizar 2 find() en un endpoint,  uno falla y retornaria un res.status(400).json({}) en caso de hacerlo, y sino continuaria el codigo asi el proximo find se ejecuta y da respuesta. El asunto que al enviar el return del error, no finaliza mi codigo, sino que continua y me tira un error de headers. Me pase toda la noche con esto y estoy agotado de no encontrar como arreglarlo! 
Adjunto las fotos a ver si pueden darme una idea de como hacer que esto funcione correctamente!

```
app.post('/endpoint', verificaToken, (req, res) =>{
let body = req.body;
let appId = body.appId;


Aplicacion.find({_id:appId}, (err, appOk) =>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err });

    if( appOk.length === 0) return res.status(404).json({ok:false, err:{message: "Aplicacion id no encontrada"}});

});

let endpointbody = _.pick(body, ['nombre', 'tipo', 'url', 'schemasAsoc', 'middlewares', 'params', 'body', 'headers']);
endpointbody.usuario = req.usuario._id;
let endpoint = new Endpoint(endpointbody);



endpoint.save((err, endpointBD) =>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err});

    Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate({_id:appId},{$push: {'backend.endpoints': endpointBD} },{runValidators: true, new:true,})

    .exec( (err, aplicacionBD) =>{

        if(err) return res.status(400).json({ ok:false, err});

        //CON ESTE RES TENGO EL ERROR, SE SIGUE ENVIANDO AUNQUE ARRIBA ESTE EL RETURN RES.STATUS(404).json({ok:false, err}) (LINEA 82)
        return res.json({ok:true, endpointBD});

    });

});
```

});

ERROR

```
    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\server\routes\endpoint.js:102:24
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4784:16
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:276:16
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4803:21
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4364:11
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4786:13
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\ideario\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:276:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es de [asincronía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asincron%C3%ADa). Y es que el método [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) de Mongoose, así como todas las [`Queries`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) son procesos asíncronos.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una petición a una base de datos MongoDB, usando el método `find()` de Mongoose, y dependiendo del resultado devolver un mensaje de error al cliente y finalizar el proceso o realizar una nueva petición a la base de datos que depende del resultado de la primera solicitud.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Puedes obtener el resultado de 2 formas:

**Usando funciones `callback`**

Para lograr el cometido debes incluir la lógica de tu programa que tienes después de tu llamada al método `find`, dentro de la función [`callback`] que estás pasando como último argumento al método `find()`:

```js
app.post('/endpoint', verificaToken, (req, res) =>{
  let body = req.body;
  let appId = body.appId;
  //llamamos al método find() del modelo
  Aplicacion.find({_id:appId}, (err, appOk) =>{
    // si hay error, devuelvo mensaje al cliente
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err });

    //si no hay registros, devuelvo mensaje al cliente
    if( appOk.length === 0) return res.status(404).json({ok:false, err:{message: "Aplicacion id no encontrada"}});

    //si hay registros, aquí continúo con la lógica de mi programa, ya que este proceso es asíncrono
    let endpointbody = _.pick(body, ['nombre', 'tipo', 'url', 'schemasAsoc', 'middlewares', 'params', 'body', 'headers']);
    endpointbody.usuario = req.usuario._id;
    let endpoint = new Endpoint(endpointbody);
    // otra llamada a un proceso asícrono, debo incluir el resto de la lógica dentro del callback pasado a este método
    endpoint.save((err, endpointBD) =>{
      // si hay error devuelvo mensaje de error
      if(err) return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err});

      //nueva llamada a otro proceso asíncrono, hacer lo mismo
      Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate({_id:appId}, {$push: {'backend.endpoints': endpointBD} },{runValidators: true, new:true,})
      .exec((err, aplicacionBD) =>{
        // si hay error, devuelvo mensaje al cliente
        if(err) return res.status(400).json({ ok:false, err});

        //si has llegado hasta aquí, es porque no se ha producido ningún error en el camino
        return res.json({ok:true, endpointBD});

      }); // <- termina Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate.exec callback
    }); // <- termina endpoint.save callback
  }); // <- termina Aplicacion.find callback
}); // <- termina app.post callback

// ^^
// Notemos la escalera de cierre de funciones `callback`
```

De esta forma corriges el error actual, sin embargo entras en lo que conocemos como `callback hell`.

**Usando `then` y `catch`**

Las `Queries` de Mongoose [**no devuelven**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas). Sin embargo proveen métodos `then()` y `catch()` para trabajar con ellas como si de una Promesa se tratara.

De esta forma podrías tener la siguiente estructura:

```js
app.post('/endpoint', verificaToken, (req, res) =>{
  let body = req.body;
  let appId = body.appId;
  //llamamos al método find() del modelo y usamos then y catch sobre el mismo
  Aplicacion.find({_id:appId})
  .then(appOk =>{
    //la instancia de error la manejaré en catch y no aqui

    //si no hay registros, devuelvo mensaje al cliente
    if( appOk.length === 0) return res.status(404).json({ok:false, err:{message: "Aplicacion id no encontrada"}});

    //si hay registros, aquí continúo con la lógica de mi programa, ya que este proceso es asíncrono
    let endpointbody = _.pick(body, ['nombre', 'tipo', 'url', 'schemasAsoc', 'middlewares', 'params', 'body', 'headers']);
    endpointbody.usuario = req.usuario._id;
    let endpoint = new Endpoint(endpointbody);
    // otra llamada a un proceso asícrono, debo incluir el resto de la lógica dentro del callback pasado a este método
    endpoint.save()
    .then(endpointBD =>{
      //la instancia de error la manejaré en catch y no aqui

      //nueva llamada a otro proceso asíncrono, hacer lo mismo
      Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate({_id:appId}, {$push: {'backend.endpoints': endpointBD} },{runValidators: true, new:true,})
      .then(aplicacionBD => {
        //la instancia de error la manejaré en catch y no aqui

        //si has llegado hasta aquí, es porque no se ha producido ningún error en el camino
        return res.json({ok:true, endpointBD});

      }) // <- termina Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate.then
      .catch(err => {
        // aqui manejo los errores Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate
        if(err) return res.status(400).json({ ok:false, err});
      }); // <- termina Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate.catch
    }) // <- termina endpoint.save.then
    .catch(err => {
      // aqui manejo los errores endpoint.save
      if(err) return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err});
    }); // <- termina endpoint.save.catch
  }) // <- termina Aplicacion.find then
  .catch(err => {
    // aqui manejo los errores de Aplicacion.find
    return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err });
  }); // <- termina Aplicacion.find catch
}); // <- termina app.post callback
```

Como podemos apreciar, también el código se vuelve bastante enredado y no nos hemos desecho realmente del llamado `callback hell`.

**Usando `async / await`**

Suponiendo que usas Node `7.10.1` o superior, puedes usar funciones [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Funcionesas%C3%ADncronas) (ver [soporte](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) en [*Node.green*](https://node.green) para funciones `async`).

Una de las características de estas funciones es que te permiten *esperar* a que un método asíncrono termine su proceso para continuar con la siguiente linea de código. Para ello tu función *middleware* debe ser declarada como una función tipo `async`.

Luego, cada llamada a procesos asíncronos puedas hacerla dentro de la función usando la palabara reservada `await`.

No olvidemos envolver el código de nuestros procesos asíncronos en un bloque [`try / catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch).

Una forma en la que podría verse tu código sería la siguiente:

```js
app.post('/endpoint', verificaToken, async (req, res) =>{
  let body = req.body;
  let appId = body.appId;
  //envolvemos la lógica de métodos asíncronos en un bloque try catch
  try {
    const appOk = await Aplicacion.find({_id:appId}); // <- usamos await
    if( appOk.length === 0) {
      // si la búsqueda en DB no arroja resultados, enviamos mensaje a cliente y finalizamos
      return res.status(404).json({ok:false, err:{message: "Aplicacion id no encontrada"}});
    }
    // si se encuentran resultados, se continúan las operaciones
    let endpointbody = _.pick(body, ['nombre', 'tipo', 'url', 'schemasAsoc', 'middlewares', 'params', 'body', 'headers']);
    endpointbody.usuario = req.usuario._id;
    let endpoint = new Endpoint(endpointbody);
    const endpointBD = await endpoint.save(); // <- usamos await
    const aplicacionBD = await Aplicacion.findOneAndUpdate({_id:appId}, {$push: {'backend.endpoints': endpointBD} },{runValidators: true, new:true,}); <- usamos await
    // si llegamos hasta aquí, no se han producido errores, podemos enviar el resultado
    return res.json({ok:true, endpointBD});
  } catch (err) {
    // si cualquiera de los métodos asíncronos resulta en error, lo capturamos aquí y enviamos el mensaje apropiado
    console.log(err.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ ok:false, err });
  }
}); // <- termina app.post callback
```

Nuestro código se ve mucho más limpio y se entiende un poco mejor la lógica de nuestro programa.

De esta forma puedes hacer la tarea que intentabas realizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio Contreras! bien claro y explicado me quedo ahora! Habia leido que una solucion era usando promesas con el async - await pero no daba en como usarlo sinceramente, ahora entendi como viene la mano y sin duda es mucho mas claro y limpio todo el codigo!